# SPF record a -all

Tags: email, spf

My DNS provider works perfectly for A records.

I am having great difficulty understanding the syntax of SPF records. I have no prior experience.

The DNS provider supports SPF records and it has two control boxes for information: 'Name' and 'SPF data'.

The A record which functions fine looks like this:

Name:   potsandpins.info
IPV4 Address:   45.61.228.207

The SPF record which is giving me no joy looks like this:

Name:  potsandpins.info
SPF Data:  "v=spf1 a -all"   (including the quotation marks)

My emails are received with a red flag in Gmail which says 'Gmail couldn't verify that potsandpins.info actually sent this message'.

Can anyone suggest anything as I've tried all sensible permutations?

Comment: Diagnose it using [Scott Kitterman's SPF validator](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html). Be aware that SPF validates the SMTP envelope sender, not the From address.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to currently have an SPF record for `potsandpins.info` maybe you deleted it because you ran into trouble. Anyway, think of the SPF as a whitelist of any IP addresses or hosts you've given permission to send email on your behalf.

The name would be either the root domain, sometimes designated by the `@`, or a hostname, `foo`, which you'd use if you were sending email out as `example@foo.example.com`.

The SPF data would be the version number (v=spf1), then mechanisms (e.g., `a`), and then the ip addresses or hosts you'd like to authorize, then the qualifier such as `-ALL`, which intends a hard fail. You may want to back off from that using `~ALL` for now, which intends a softfail. I think it's better to be specific in SPF records as then they're easier to follow exactly what they're authorizing.

Here's an example SPF record. Let's say you wanted to authorize 192.0.2.10 and Google.

`v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.10 include:_spf.google.com ~all`

Let's say you wanted to authorize a range of IP addresses and MailChimp:

`v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.0/24 include:servers.mcsv.net ~all`

Here's a good article on [common mistakes in SPF records](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes).

Then it's important to validate your SPF record using a tool such as the [SPF Survey](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/). I like this tool because it gives more detailed, actionable error messages when there's a problem.

if you post the full headers of an example email and indicate any other services you use to send email, then it would be possible to provide more specific advice. For future reference, it's best to provide more details when you post to Stack Overflow as that makes it easier to help. I tried in this post but the information you provided limited how specific the answer could be.

Also, for future reference, it's best to post using `example.com` rather than a real domain name and use IP addresses from an [IPv4 block reserved for documentation.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737)

> The blocks 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2),
> and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3) are provided for use in documentation.

Anyway, I hope this helps.